# Factory reset, cannot reload Google paly

Tags: google-play-store

I was having issues with my android tablet so I performed a factory reset.  Now, I am trying to get my Google Play account re-installed so I can download apps.  I keep getting a "cannot connect to Google servers" message.  For a week now I cannot connect to get any aps, did I do something wrong doing a factory reset? is my tablet useless now?  Please help

Comment: Were you able to successfully add your Gmail/Google account during the Setup Wizard? Your Google account is needed for Play Services and Google Play to update themselves (this is accomplished automatically).

Answer (score 0):

You have to remove two step verification of your gmail account.
to do so,

In “Signing in & security” section of My Account, select 2-Step Verification. Sign in with your username, password, and verification code if asked.
Select Turn off 2-Step Verification.
A pop-up window will appear to confirm that you want to turn off 2-Step Verification. Select Ok.